# convert NSDate to GMT timezone

Tags: ios, nsdate

I am working on NSDate and i am new for it.I have start date and end date,getting from user.And it is `2013-01-01 and 2013-02-19`.When i try to display in console it is showing me `2012-12-31 18:30:00 +0000`.So you can say `5:30` is gap.So i am adding time interval

```
startDate = [aStartdDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:19800];
endDate = [aEndDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:19800];
```

My question is when i am trying to get current week using `2012-12-31 18:30:00 +0000` date, it is showing me correctly.But when i use `2013-02-01 00:00:00 +0000` date,it is showing me total number of weeks in month.Please help me.Thanking you.

Comment: how you are getting week number can you post that code?

Comment: using this code- NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSRange weekRange = [calendar rangeOfUnit:NSWeekCalendarUnit inUnit:NSMonthCalendarUnit forDate:date];int weeks = week range.length;

Comment: You need to separate the concept of `NSDate` and time zones in your mind, they are **not connected**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timezones shouldn't be part of your model - They are a presentation problem.
Your model should always use a common default timezone. If you present the date to your users, apply a `NSDateFormatter` that uses a [specific timezone](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000447-CJBICCJE).

In your case this means, that you shouldn't try to fix your dates by applying arbitrary intervals but use a date formatter in the final step (output) instead.